# From list returned by query to integer in Tornado

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment, tornado

I have those variables:

```
PERM_READ = 0x01
PERM_WRITE = 0x02
PERM_CMDS = 0x04
```

and a function that check the permission on a network or on a sensor. A function that determines what is the permission of the user.

This is the function:

```
def check_network_access(self, network, access=None, raise_err=True):
    if access is None:
        access = PERM_READ
    else:
        assert(access > 0)
        assert(access <= (PERM_READ + PERM_WRITE + PERM_CMDS))
    usr = self.get_current_user()
    usr_id = usr['id']
    # Does the network exist?
    net = self.get_network(network)
    if not net:
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404, "not found")

    self.lock_tables('read', ['nets_permissions'])
    perms = self.db.get("SELECT * FROM nets_permissions WHERE network_id=%s AND \
                        user_id=%s", network, usr_id)
    self.unlock_tables()
    if (not perms) or ((perms['perm'] & access) != access):
        if (raise_err):
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(403, "access forbidden %s %s", perms['perm'], access)
        else: 
            return False
    return True
```

Now for example i have an error when I call a page with this handler:

```
class NetworkStatusHandler(BaseHandler):
# Requires authentication 
@tornado.web.authenticated
def get(self, nid):

    # Retrieve the current user 
    usr = self.get_current_user()
    usr_id = usr['id']

    perm = self.db.query("SELECT n.perm FROM nets_permissions as n \
                          WHERE n.network_id=%s AND n.user_id=%s", nid, int(usr_id))

    # Check whether the user has access to the network 
    perms = self.check_network_access(nid, perm)
    net = self.get_network(nid)
    # Render the networks page
    self.render("networkstatus.html", net=net)
```

The error I have is:

```
File "./wsn.py", line 264, in check_network_access
raise tornado.web.HTTPError(403, "access forbidden %s %s", perms['perm'], access)
HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden (access forbidden 4 1)
```

I think this is a problem in the passing of the cariable perm/access to the function... How I have to pass this variable in order to do this is an integer and not a list?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why you thinking? Have checked what exactly you passed to `check_network_access`?

Comment: I don't know how I can see variables in Tornado. I don't know how I can do a debug! Please help me

Comment: but where in the html page I see the variables?

Comment: start your tornado application server in console, and then print statements will go there.

Comment: what is the command to print? self.write(access)?

Comment: no!) command for print is `print` =)

Comment: Look at my answer below. It's right?

Comment: statement is correct. your tornado app must by default write info in console. btw, if it's not working at all - just raise exceptions, and use them as print. but it's terrible practice.

Comment: Ok in this way I have that perm is {'perm': 4L} so I want to pass to the function the integer value 4.

Comment: You want to sanitize input value in function and make `int(perm)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right way:

```
class NetworkStatusHandler(BaseHandler):
# Requires authentication 
@tornado.web.authenticated
def get(self, nid):

    # Retrieve the current user 
    usr = self.get_current_user()
    usr_id = usr['id']

    self.lock_tables("read", ['nets_permissions as n'])
    perm = self.db.get("SELECT n.perm FROM nets_permissions as n \
                          WHERE n.network_id=%s AND n.user_id=%s", nid, int(usr_id))
    self.unlock_tables()

    # Check whether the user has access to the network
    perms = self.check_network_access(nid, perm['perm'])
    net = self.get_network(nid)
    # Render the networks page
    self.render("networkstatus.html", net=net)
```

with self.db.get and perm['perm'] . Thank you!!!!